Can we lower the number of votes required to close a question?
To close a question, it takes five votes from users with at least 500 reputation or one moderator vote, which is final.
(Edit: As noted in D. Ben Knoble's answer, users with a gold tag badge can dupe hammer to close with a single vote. AFAIK, no user has earned a gold tag badge as of now.)
I noticed we rarely manage to close a question without a moderator vote.
What concerns me is that this puts an undue responsibility and pressure on moderators.
It also runs contrary to the by the community, for the community idea behind the Stack Exchange sites.
To me, it seems five votes are too much for the number of 500+ reputation users of this site.
Note that on Stack Overflow, the godfather of SE sites, only three votes are needed to close a question.
I'm asking:

Can we change the number of close votes at all? If not, we can close this question.
Why is it five here but only three on SO? Was this a deliberate choice or is it the default for SE sites? I'm asking just out of curiosity.
Should we change the number of votes to close? If yes, what would be a good number? (I'd be in favor of: three, as on SO)

I'm especially curious about feedback from the moderator team.
Less close votes needed would mean a bigger share of site moderation/curation could be handled by the non-mod community.
Would it make your life easier?

I went through the ten most recently closed questions.
In each and every of these questions, the final vote was a moderator vote.
So not a single question in my sample of ten was closed without moderator intervention.
Only four out of ten questions were closed through the regular five votes.
The rest of them were moderator decisions.
In my sample, there was no unilateral moderator decision, which I appreciate.

Rene was kind enough to create and share a SEDE query to show the number of closed questions by votes:



close votes
# of questions




10
1


6
2


5
238


4
86


3
104


2
131


1
233



If I read this table correctly, a threshold of three close votes  would mean at least 190 (of 795) questions would have been closed by regular user votes alone.
This is almost 24%.
The query to find the most prolific closers is headed by (former) moderators.
This seems to back the "we need a mod to close" theory.
I was actually surprised to see my name far higher up on that list than my low reputation and short tenure on this site would suggest.
I knew I like to cast close votes, I didn't know it was that bad.

Do know that SEDE has PostHistory records for close events where it stores all voters once a question gets closed. You can then query that table like so: https://data.stackexchange.com/vi/query/1880942 (do know this only includes non-deleted posts).

Maybe useful as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323259



Can we change the number of close votes at all? If not, we can close this question.


Yes, and:

in the case of Hardware Recommendations, a moderator contacted the CMs (?) because they participated overwhelmingly in closing questions; this led to tests and an eventual change in the number of votes.
StackOverflow's history with this seems a bit turbulent, and it's hard for me to reconstruct just by searching meta.SO. This Q&A suggests (via duplicate) that the move from 5 to 3 was made permanent in 2019. This search of the relevant tag from 2020–2024 suggests there hasn't been much change.



Why is it five here but only three on SO? Was this a deliberate choice or is it the default for SE sites? I'm asking just out of curiosity.


Note that it only takes 1 vote from a gold-tag-badge holder to close duplicates.
Beyond that, yes: I read the FAQ as saying that 5 is the default. I certainly never filled in a form that opted for any particular number.
Here's some history about how it got to be that way (originally only 3 were required).
Here's some more sites that got a reduction (if I skimmed that right).


Should we change the number of votes to close? If yes, what would be a good number? (I'd be in favor of: three, as on SO)


Let me see if I can start up a conversation with the other mods and the CM folks to at least pull data to share.


Would it make your life easier?

I can only speak for myself, but I do still feel some of the "beta" (as in, before we graduated) pressure to review to make sure that action is taken when consensus is formed. Otherwise I feel that (but don't have data to back this up) some items languish in queues just shy of requisite votes.
Whether that is backed by data, I do not know. If someone knows how to find out, I would greatly appreciate seeing how often queue items sit short one or two votes (and how many of those are "rescued" by a moderator vote). (Based on my research for HW Recs, the CM team can probably pull that data easily).

"I can only speak for myself" - you're speaking for 50% of this site's moderators :-) Thank you for your very elaborate answer, more than I was hoping for. Reading through the linked Q&As it seems we qualify as a site where "moderators are doing most of the work". It pretty much boils down to: how much of a pain it is for you (and the other 50% of the mod team)?

@Friedrich It would certainly be nice to not be needed for most reviews ;)
